# Repaint doesn't erase the background (sometimes)

Tags: java, swing

I put a `aintComponent()` method in a `JPanel`. This method draws a tree using `Graphics.drawLine()`.

I put a `JButton` from which a Listener is used to zoom on this tree. At the end I use the `repaint()` method, and my tree is repainted bigger, so no problem there.

```
 // Add Listeners on Zooming buttons
 bPlus.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

        Node.setZoom(1);
        repaint();
         }
   });
```

However, I used a `MouseMotionListener` for moving this tree inside its JPanel.
Then when I call `repaint()`, it does not erase the previous printed trees, so I end up with duplicated trees.

```
 addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() { 
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    if(mouseHolded) {
    x += e.getX() - mouseX;
    mouseX = e.getX();
    y += e.getY() - mouseY;
    mouseY = e.getY();
    repaint();       // <===

  }
}
  }
);
```

What am I doing wrong ? While the previous trees will be erased when I use the `repaint()` for zooming, why wont it do so when I move the tree?

Comment: Sounds like you are not calling `super.paintComponent` before you paint your tree

Comment: Actually the repaint() for zoom is written ni my JFrame. The one for moving is written in my JPanel which is included in the JFrame.
I tried putting the repaint in the JFrame and it worked...

Comment: I don't quite understand: why wont calling my_jpanel.repaint() work since paintComponent() is located in this class?
Why is it working in the including JFrame only?

Comment: I think you have the same behavior both times, but zoom just happens to paint a picture that entirely covers the previous one, where with translation this doesn't happen. Your original image is not being erased.

Comment: One of the jobs of `paintComponent` is to prepare the `Graphics` context for painting, this typically involves filling it with the background color of the component.  If you fail to call `super.paintComponent`, the `Graphics` context may contain results of previous paint operations.  Check out [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: Also, `repaint` is a request made to the `RepaintManager` that may result in the entire window been repainted.  So even if you call `repaint` on the panel, it cause the window to be repainted

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)